# What do you need to enter in <IPC_LOCATION> of geth attach <IPC LOCATION>

Tags: go-ethereum

What do you need to enter in <IPC_LOCATION> of geth attach

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running the Geth client, an `.ipc` file is created. You need to put the path to that file. Here are the default locations, as per the [Geth docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/server):

MacOS/Linux:

```
~/.ethereum/geth.ipc
```

Windows:

```
\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```